# performance impact when add/remove node in Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, scale, addition

As far as I know, adding a new node into the cassandra cluster would have to copy the data from the hosting node to the new node. Would this heavily impact the performance of the existing node? Also, if the replication_factor is, say 3, I guess there should be also data transfer and management of the nodes that host the data replicas. What is the performance indication to these replica nodes?

For example, if I observe that a node receives very high workload and I want to add a new node to take care a portion of the data, what is the detailed step-by-step procedures happening for both the hosting node and other replica nodes?

Similar problem for removing a node from the cluster.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adding a new node will increase the load on the existing nodes, therefore it is wise to increase the size of your cluster before it starts struggling. Removing a node inherently increases the load on the remaining nodes.

You can check the following video for some insight on what happens when you add a new node (from 1:27):
http://planetcassandra.org/video-presentations/vp/cassandra-summit-europe-2014/vd/instaclustr-streaming-from-backups-reducing-cluster-load-when-adding-nodes/

Comment: Excellent video.  Honestly I never would have through to try bootstrapping from a backup.  I talked with the Instaclustr guys at the Cassandra SF summit this year.  "Cassandra as a service" is definitely a cool idea.

Comment: Just got to the end of the video.  Bootstrapping from a snapshot isn't available just yet.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is not available yet. I linked the video because it explains well what happens when a new node is added to the cluster.